# What is this GUI principle called?

Tags: user-interface

"Prefer to design UI that guides the user to provide correct input before submitting a form over presenting an error message when he submits it incorrectly"

Is there a canonical link that explains this (similar to [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you accept the following?

> An ounce of prevention is better than a cure.

Comment: It's not a canonical link (but this question could become such a link if Google wills it) :)

I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a methodology name just for that technique, but in general this type of thing would fall under [Interaction Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_design#User-centered_interaction_design).

The following links would help you as well (based on user-centric interface design):

- [User Interface Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_design)
- [Experience Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experience_design)